# What are some mRNA vaccines, other than COVID vaccines, that are widely used?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

From what I've read, COVID vaccines belong to [mRNA vaccines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_vaccine) category.

I read in the above article that mRNA vaccines act in a **different way than traditional vaccines.**

> [..]Traditional vaccines stimulate an antibody response by injecting antigens, an attenuated virus (weakened or harmless virus), or a recombinant antigen-encoding viral vector (carrier virus engineered to have antigens) into muscles. These antigen-containing ingredients are prepared and grown outside the body.

> In contrast, mRNA vaccines introduce a synthetically created fragment of the RNA sequence of a virus into the vaccinated individual. These mRNA fragments are taken up dendritic cells – a type of immune system cell – by phagocytosis.[14] The dendritic cells use their own internal machinery to read the mRNA and produce the viral antigens that the mRNA encodes.[..]

My question is: are there **any known mRNA vaccines, other than COVID vaccines** that have been **widely adopted by any country** (e.g. as part of the national vaccination program)?

Comment: mRNA vaccines are a relatively new endeavor.  Note that some vaccines will be based on mRNA, while others will not. You have to research each vaccine to see how it works, or find a table somewhere that someone has already created (if I knew of one, I would link to it for you!).

Comment: You can easily find [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_vaccine#History) that the answer is no.

Answer (score 4):

There are no other mRNA vaccines with an allowance for use yet. There have been promising tests before COVID-19 though. See this review article:

Pardi, N., Hogan, M., Porter, F. et al. mRNA vaccines — a new era in vaccinology. Nat Rev Drug Discov 17, 261–279 (2018). https://doi.org/10.1038/nrd.2017.243

Available [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrd.2017.243)  (Last accessed December 2020)

Comment: This is pretty much what's known as a link-only answer, which are heavily frowned upon 
 on stackexchange because links rot over time. If nature.com ever decides to reorganize their web site, your link will possibly become dead, thereby rendering your answer useless. Please find the relevant section in your link and quote it in your answer so if the link ever goes dead, your question will still be useful.

Comment: @CareyGregory the link is now permanent.